# How can I get a value from an unknown enum in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

I'm actually programming a deepToString-Method that extends object. This uses reflection to get each property of an object and calls the deepToString-Method for this property. Everything works fine except of Enums. If I try to use `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` with an enum, it allways returns zero.

How can I get the real int-Value? What am I missing?

Comment: Could you show us the code that does not work, and a short sample of a class with an enum the value of which it fails to get? The method you describe should just work, there must be something special about your class or about the way you access the enum.

Comment: Stupid me! You're right. The Value hasn't been set. That was the reason, why it resulted in "0". 'PropertyInfo.GetValue(object, null)' works great :)

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in your_class.GetType().GetProperties())
{
  if ((info.PropertyType.IsEnum) && (info.PropertyType.IsPublic))
  {
    foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in this.propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
    {
      ListItem item = new ListItem(fInfo.Name, fInfo.GetRawConstantValue().ToString());
      //... use it
    }
  }
}
```

I have to add that reflection is EVIL. Rare are the occasions where it is really needed..

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. But I wanted to get the value of an instance of an unknown enum, not all possible values.
I'm just using this for the testing-ui, cause i'm to lazy to write a toString-Method for each data-object i wrote. I'll never use it in release-code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Foo
{
    Boo,
    Koo
}

public Foo foo { get; set; }

[Fact]
public void FactMethodName()
{
    foo = Foo.Koo;
    var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty("foo");
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("value = {0}", value); //prints Koo
        int asInt = (int)value;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("asInt = {0}", asInt); //prints 1
    }
}
```